# Bibliography International Macroeconomics/Finance

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-economics, open-economy-macro

I'm looking for some bibliography for International Macroeconomics/Finance. Any suggestions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is a very broad category. Could you please be more specific- what type of bibliography? Papers or textbooks? Empirical work or DSGE models?

Comment: @ChinG I was thinking textbooks, and some could include DSGE models.

Comment: Obstfeld and Rogoff, Foundations of International Macroeconomics, is a standard reference.

Comment: @AntonTarasenko Thanks ;)  By the way, the book was published in 1996. Is the material still up to date?

Comment: While the book is old, it continues to be one of the main, if not the main reference for international macro/finance :)